# Python script for converting CSV to JSON for use with Auth0 has problems after system upgrade

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

This script is designed to convert a CSV to JSON for user with Auth0, and was previously working until I moved to a new machine - after multiple python upgrades, module installs, and attempted fixes, I've reached the end of my bug-whacking prowess.

```
import csv, json, bcrypt, sys

csvPath = sys.argv[1]
jsonPath = sys.argv[2]

data = []

f = open( csvPath, 'r' )  
reader = csv.DictReader( f, fieldnames = ( "name","email","password" ))  
next(reader)
for row in reader:
    entry = {}
    sub1 = {}
    sub2 = {}
    pwd = row['password']
    password = pwd.encode('utf-8')
    salt = bcrypt.gensalt(rounds=10)
    sub2['value'] = bcrypt.hashpw(password, salt)
    entry['name'] = row['name']
    entry['email'] = row['email']
    entry['email_verified'] = True
    sub1['algorithm'] = 'bcrypt'
    sub1['hash'] = sub2
    entry['custom_password_hash'] = sub1
    
    data.append(entry)

out = json.dumps( data )  

print ("JSON parsed!")
f = open( jsonPath , 'w')  
f.write(out)
print ("JSON saved")
```

I was initially getting a `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing` error, which prompted me to add the `.encode` on line 16.

That changed the error to this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python-auth0.py", line 28, in <module>
    out = json.dumps( data )  
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

I attempted to add a decode attribute to 'data' in line 28, which led to `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'`

So I'm clearly just making wild stabs in the dark here - any help to get this working again would be appreciated!

Comment: unrelated .. you never close your file ... use `with open( jsonPath , 'w') as f: f.write(out)`

Comment: Thank you @PatrickArtner - I added that change in as well as the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you can do is that you decode the hashed back into a python string

```py
import json, bcrypt

pwd = "mypassword"
password = pwd.encode('utf-8')
salt = bcrypt.gensalt(rounds=10)
hashed_pwd = bcrypt.hashpw(password, salt)
decoded_hash = hashed_pwd.decode('utf-8')

# this will raise exception
print(json.dumps(hashed_pwd))

# this will not
print(json.dumps(decoded_hash))
```

in your case, try:

```py
import csv, json, bcrypt, sys

csvPath = sys.argv[1]
jsonPath = sys.argv[2]

data = []

f = open( csvPath, 'r' )  
reader = csv.DictReader( f, fieldnames = ( "name","email","password" ))  
next(reader)
for row in reader:
    entry = {}
    sub1 = {}
    sub2 = {}
    pwd = row['password']
    password = pwd.encode('utf-8')
    salt = bcrypt.gensalt(rounds=10)
    sub2['value'] = bcrypt.hashpw(password, salt).decode('utf-8') # <-- here
    entry['name'] = row['name']
    entry['email'] = row['email']
    entry['email_verified'] = True
    sub1['algorithm'] = 'bcrypt'
    sub1['hash'] = sub2
    entry['custom_password_hash'] = sub1
    
    data.append(entry)

out = json.dumps( data )  

print ("JSON parsed!")
f = open( jsonPath , 'w')  
f.write(out)
print ("JSON saved")
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it!